# .gitignore wildcard not working? ("LIVE-* " pattern doesn't match "LIVE-vhost" filename)

Tags: git, gitignore

Super quick one. Here is my .gitignore (at the root level of my repo

```
# Makefile stuff
LIVE-* 
.install-post-all
```

When I do this, The LIVE-* bit isn't working:

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   pm-h8/etc/apache2/conf.d/LIVE-vhost
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Remove the blank space after the string you want to match.

Answer (score 8):

Try wildcarding the directory as well:

```
**/LIVE-*
```

Comment: Nope, still no luck :( any other ideas? this one has me stumped